# httpd.exe: Syntax error, PHP 5.2.17 in uWamp server

Tags: uwamp

I wanted to update a old project i've made. Its written in PHP version:5.2.17. When I downloaded the correct version for uWamp I recieve this error

httpd.exe: Syntax error on line 166 of C:/UwAmp/bin/apache/conf/httpd.conf: LoadModule takes two arguments, a module name and the name of a shared object file to load it from.

Can somebody help me with this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you have the right Visual C++ Redistributable x86, like they tell on [the download page](http://www.uwamp.com/en/?page=download).

Same error but with a recent php version, corrected with installation of the right file.

> Before use UwAmp you must install Visual C++ Redistributable x86 version  vc_redist.x86.exe. This is a PHP requirement.
>
> - For PHP older version you need : Download VC6 2005 vc_redist.x86.exe
> - For PHP 5.3 you need : Download VC9 2008 vc_redist.x86.exe
> - For PHP 5.4+ you need : Download VC11 2012 vc_redist.x86.exe
> - For PHP 7.x+ you need : Download VC14 2015 vc_redist.x86.exe

Comment: Thanks! I only installed the 64 bit versions. Didn't knowing 32 bit would work!

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem with older version of php (5.2.17).
If you open the file with a text editor (C:/UwAmp/bin/apache/conf/httpd.conf) and go to the line 166 you can edit the file, but when the Apache module starts again, the file is regenerated and the error came again.
(sorry for my bad english :)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).